# Why I cannot login to my magento admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-login

My username and password is correct and it only redirects to the login page after I login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, you may need to remove all cookies related to your site and refresh the page.

> To do this, open your admin area in tab, right click anywhere and
>   select "inspect"
>
> Go to the Applications tab in the Developer Tools window
>
> In the left column, look for Storage. Inside of that is Cookies.
>   Expand that view and select your website from the list.
>
> Right click your website and select Clear

Refresh the admin page you are on and try logging in again.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have a staging site you're using - set different cookie domains accordingly - or only work in staging on Incognito.